# How to block a ScrollPane panel JavaFX

Tags: javafx, resizable, scrollpane

I have a small problem. I'm building an interface with JavaFX like this:
[image: interface JavaFX]
I wonder, how can I do to block those "lines" of the ScrollPane I indicated in the image? Practically it is not to be resizable but among its properties the ScrollPane does not allow me to put the check on that property:

[image: Properties]

How can I do to solve?
thanks to all in advance!

Comment: this isn't SplitPane ?

Comment: Yes, sorry. The all is in a SplitPane and inside there is the ScrollPane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that you have not added a minimum value to your `ScrollPanes` here's an example :

```
    SplitPane split = new SplitPane();
    split.setPrefSize(400, 400); 

    //First ScrollPane
    ScrollPane spA = new ScrollPane();
    spA.setMinWidth(100);  //Block the scrollPane width to 100
    spA.setFitToHeight(true);
    spA.setFitToWidth(true); 
    Pane paneA = new Pane();
    paneA.setStyle("-fx-background-color:red;");
    spA.setContent(paneA);

    //Second ScrollPane
    ScrollPane spB = new ScrollPane();
    spB.setMinWidth(100); //Block the scrollPane width to 100
    spB.setFitToHeight(true);
    spB.setFitToWidth(true); 
    Pane paneB = new Pane();
    paneB.setStyle("-fx-background-color:blue;");
    spB.setContent(paneB);

    split.getItems().addAll(spA,spB);
```

To be able to use your scrollPane as it grows, you can use the binding and bind the content's (width/height properties) of your `ScrollPane` to their parents (ScrollPane) example :

```
//set the (FitToHeight/FitToWidth) properties to false before !
spA.widthProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {

            paneB.setMinWidth((double)newValue);
        }
    });
```

Good luck !

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much!